# Python Tkinter GUI bind 'Return' to function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, bind

I am having trouble figuring out how to bind the 'Enter' key with a function or more specifically a button.  I want to bind the 'Enter' key with the self.search function.  I have the code below and I have tried many different ways.  Right now it just clears the entry box.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class MainGUI:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.minsize(width=500, height=175)
    master.title("Serial Number Decode")

    self.label = Label(master, text="Serial Number Decoder")
    self.label.pack()
    self.textBox=Text(master, height=1, width=30)
    self.textBox.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor='n')
    self.textBox2=Text(master, height=2, width=50,font=("Sans",12))

    self.textBox2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='s')
    self.search_button = Button(master, text="Search", command=self.search)
    self.search_button.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.15, anchor='w')

    #self.search_button.bind('<Return>', self.search)

    self.master.bind('<Return>', self.search) #Just clears the entry box

    self.multiLook_button = Button(master, text="MultiLook", command=self.multiLook)
    self.multiLook_button.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.6, anchor='w')

    self.multiSearch_button = Button(master, text="MultiSearch", command=self.multiSearch)
    self.multiSearch_button.place(relx=0.84, rely=0.6, anchor='w')

    self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
    self.close_button.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.15, anchor='w')
```

Comment: You bound the key correctly. The problem must be in the self.search function, which you did not show us.

Comment: You are correct.  I needed to add the event=None to the search function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, assuming you have `search` defined in the class, like so:

```
class MainGUI():

    def __init__(self, master):
        # ... Code ...


    def search(self, event):
        # ... Code ...
```

You can access the method as you are:

```
self.search_button.bind('<Return>', self.search)
```

Using this approach, the `search_button` widget must have the focus, in order for event binding to be triggered when Enter is pressed.

Additionally, I'm going to suggest a different way to structure your application, that will help to add readability to your code, and allow for easier scaling, say if you wanted to add to the app in the future. It's best to take a methodical approach when developing a GUI, i.e. systematic, or step by step - modularity can help with this.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainGUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master.minsize(width=500, height=175)
        self.master.title("Serial Number Decode")

        self.main_label()
        self.text_boxes()
        self.buttons()


    def main_label(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Serial Number Decoder')
        self.label.pack()


    def text_boxes(self):
        # First we create the widgets
        self.textBox = tk.Text(self, height=1, width=30)
        self.textBox2 = tk.Text(self, height=2, width=50, font=("Sans",12))

        # Next place them within the GUI
        self.textBox.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor='n')
        self.textBox2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='s')


    def buttons(self):
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self, text="Search", command=self.search)

        # You can set a widget to have the 'focus' like so:
        self.search_button.focus()

        # And bind an event on focus in, focus out, enter, shift, etc. - e.g.:
        self.search_button.bind('<FocusIn>', self.do_something)
        self.search_button.bind('<FocusOut>', self.do_something_else)
        self.search_button.bind('<Return>', self.search)

        # Other buttons below...


    def search(self, event=None):
        # Do something now that the event has been triggered
```

A couple things to note - `def search(self, event=None)`, I give the event keyword argument here a default value of `None` because if the button is clicked (from setting `command=self.search`), an 'event' will **not** be passed to the method, however if the method is triggered from a binding, the 'event' will be passed. Also, I wasn't very thorough in my code example, I wrote pieces of code, and structured it, purely for example's sake, e.g. I didn't register the search button with the GUI, so it won't appear, or `self.do_something` isn't defined so running this will actually raise an `AttributeError`. I hope this all helps! Lastly here is a great resource for tkinter, [NMT Tkinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the help and the tips on structure.  I changed it up and added the 'event=None' to the search function and it works now